# How cometd server send response to /meta/connect message

Tags: cometd

How CometD send response to a /meta/connect message.

Also how cometd receive/send message received on any broadcast channel. Are there any message queues involved?

If there is queue involved then will /meta/connect will also be en queued into this? Does this queue exist on client side as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the [CometD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org), in particular the [CometD Concepts](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_concepts).

Comment: So basically broadcast messages are enqueud into server session's message message queue and then sent to client as payloads of transport-specific envelopes? One thing here will it send these messages in queue one by one or as an batch. How is /meta/connect messages are sent, if they are not queued, does it mean that they are sent as and when they come as payloads of transport-specific envelopes?

Comment: Whether messages are sent in batches of not depend on the transport and on the configuration. `/meta/connect` responses are sent when they are required to be sent, considering numerous factors such as timeouts, presence of extensions and occasion.